# AAD MSGraph - How to see what groups are attached to an AAD connected App?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I have a C# Web app that our business uses to invite guest users to our AAD and put users in groups.

We use this C# web app instead of the portal, because it presents the data a little more friendlier way to the business, supports workflow, can do some audit on inputted data, customize the invite email message, etc.

To support this application, I have to maintain in my apps local config a mapping of AAD group object ids to AAD App Object ID.  Actually my app doesn't really use any AAD concept of app.

Is there a way I can lighten my configuration, and be more dynamic? I would like to drop my lists of groups, instead asking AAD for the groups connected to each app I care about.

I have just started to look at

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/approleassignment

but I don't quite understand how to chain the different calls together to get back a list of group oids..

Any advice/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. To find users assigned to an app, you will need to get the application's service principal's app role assignments.

So assuming you know your service principal's object id:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/eea0d6cd-20e2-aaaa-97ca-5b0cbffac985/appRoleAssignments
```

This is not available on the v1.0 endpoint, only beta of MS Graph API. Since beta is not supported in production, you can also access a basically identical URL in Azure AD Graph API (the API being integrated into MS Graph API).

Here is an example response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#appRoleAssignments",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "JYrDc-sj60S_Y0qph7LvGf1WEjyOr5NKvhK_v1NTME8",
            "creationTimestamp": null,
            "principalDisplayName": "Test User",
            "principalId": "73c38a25-23eb-aaaa-bf63-4aa987b2ef19",
            "principalType": "User",
            "resourceDisplayName": "My App",
            "resourceId": "eea0d6cd-20e2-aaaa-97ca-5b0cbffac985"
        },
        {
            "id": "aLvuP_x1q0GACPZxznTP9w24cypievFBrGx-mNsCWGE",
            "creationTimestamp": "2017-01-26T19:33:48.8356667Z",
            "principalDisplayName": "Another User",
            "principalId": "3feebb68-75fc-aaaa-8008-f671ce74cff7",
            "principalType": "User",
            "resourceDisplayName": "My App",
            "resourceId": "eea0d6cd-20e2-aaaa-97ca-5b0cbffac985"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now my Free AAD does not allow group assignment so there are only user assignments here. But the only difference is that `principalType` will be `"Group"`, and the `principalId` will be the group object id.

If *you don't know the service principal object id*, you can get it by using the app's client id like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '1c9fdc91-aaaa-aaaa-af8d-027507190f41'
```

This also does not work in the v1.0 endpoint.

The URLs for Azure AD Graph API would be:

```
https://graph.windows.net/tenant-id/servicePrincipals/eea0d6cd-20e2-aaaa-97ca-5b0cbffac985/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

And to get the service principal object id by client id:

```
https://graph.windows.net/tenant-id/servicePrincipalsByAppId/1c9fdc91-aaaa-aaaa-af8d-027507190f41/objectId?api-version=1.6
```

Replace *tenant-id* with your Azure AD tenant id or verified domain e.g. myorg.onmicrosoft.com.